# DBI - Perl - Logging MySQL warnings

Tags: mysql, perl, warnings, dbi

I am using DBI and looking to add logging for MySQL WARNINGS to this script.  I am able to log true MySQL errors without problem but at this point I need to track down MySQL Warnings that are being generated.   If the mysql statement fails I am able to print the bad sql statement to bad_sql.txt  and autogenerate an email. I need to make two changes and I really stuck
1)If the statement executes but there is a mysql warning I want to capture that to last_sql_warning.txt
2)If the statement failes do to a lock timeout i would like to re-submit the query up to two times.

This is what gets dumped in to the log now.

`MiscLibs::MySQL::MySQLDoCmd, MySQL.pm line 564:

-->UPDATE tbl_xxx_files SET ReloadStart=123" WHERE (FileName="image.txt")<--`

Relevant Block of code

```
#=====================================================================================
# Execute MySQL commands and handle errors
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLDoCmd ($;$) {

my ($MySQLCmd, $Quite) = @_;

 if ( eval { $DBHandle->do($MySQLCmd) } ) {
   open (MYFILE2, '>/bb/bin/fa/logs/last_sql_warning.txt');
   # trying to write warning to log.  As a first pass I was attempting to write 
   # each statement to the log and include any warnings.  What I would like code to
   # do is check if there is a warning and only then write that statement to the log. 

   print MYFILE2 MySQLMakeID() . ": $DBHandle->errstr\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";

return 0;

} elsif ( ! $Quite ) {
  open (MYFILE, '>>/bb/bin/fa/logs/badsql.txt');
  print MYFILE  MySQLMakeID() . ": $@\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";

#=========SENDS EMAIL ON STATEMENT FAILURE===================
 while (my ($addressee, $address) = each (%emailList))
 {
     print STDERR "INFO: Sending email to $addressee at address $address\n";
     $message =~ s/ADDRESSEE/$addressee/g;
     $message =~ s/ERRORREASON/$errMessage/g;
     &sendMail($addressee, $address, $message);
     $message =~ s/$addressee/ADDRESSEE/g;
     $message =~ s/$errMessage/ERRORREASON/g;
  }

return 1;

 } else {
  return 1;

 }

}
```

Full Block of code

```
use strict;                        # Everything must be defined before it is used
use warnings;                      # Print warnings
use POSIX;                         # Provides POSIX functions
use English '-no_match_vars';      # Provides access to English version of builtin variables
use Net::SMTP;

#===================================================================================================

package MiscLibs::MySQL;
use Exporter ();

our ($VERSION, @ISA, @EXPORT, @EXPORT_OK);

$VERSION = '1.00';
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT_OK = ( );
@EXPORT = qw( 

MySQLOpenConnection
MySQLCloseConnection

MySQLCloseHandle

MySQLErrNo
MySQLError
MySQLHostInfo
MySQLInfo
MySQLInsertID
MySQLProtoInfo
MySQLServerInfo
MySQLStat
MySQLThreadID
MySQLDBDStats
MySQLAutoReconnect
MySQLUseResult
MySQLShowTables
MySQLShowColumns
MySQLValidateFields
MySQLNumOfFields
MySQLErrStr
MySQLUseResults

MySQLDoCmd

MySQLDeleteRows
MySQLDeleteRowsICS
MySQLInsertRow
MySQLUpdateRows

MySQLSelectRows
MySQLGetHashRef
MySQLGetArray
MySQLSetLastUpdate
MySQLSetReportState

MySQLTruncateTable
MySQLDisableKeys
MySQLEnableKeys
MySQLOptimizeTable

MySQLCacheAddTable
MySQLCacheAddBuffer
MySQLCacheFlush

);
#=====================================================================================
my %emailList = (
                   "bob"=>"\@bog.com",
               );

my $errMessage = "error_message";
my $message = "MySQl Query Timed out - check logs/";

#======================================================================================
 sub sendMail()
{
 #not relevant - smtp code

     print "EXECUTE: Mail sent successfully\n";
}

#======================================================================================

use File::Basename;                # Provides basename, dirname and fileparse functions
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;                           # Interface to MySQL

my $DBHandle;

my %CacheFieldNameStrings;
my %CacheFieldNameArrays;
my %CacheSizes;
my %CacheFieldValues;
my %CacheDupKeyCmds;

my %ValidateFieldNames;

my $MaxCacheSize = 50;

1;

#=====================================================================================
# Create an ID string for error reporting
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLMakeID {

  my ($package, $filepath, $line, $subroutine, $hasargs,
      $wantarray, $evaltext, $is_require, $hints, $bitmask) = caller(1);

  $subroutine =~ s/main:://;

  my $filename = basename($filepath);

  my $id = "$subroutine, $filename line $line";

  # print "ID: '$id'\n";

  return $id;

}

#=====================================================================================
# Open MySQL connection and get reference information
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLOpenConnection (;$) {

  my ( $NewMaxCacheSize ) = @_;

  my $Database;
  my $Host;
  my $Port;
  my $DSN;
  my $User;
  my $Password;
  my %Options;

  if ( defined($NewMaxCacheSize) && ($NewMaxCacheSize > 1) ) { $MaxCacheSize = $NewMaxCacheSize }

  $Database = $ENV{MySQLDatabase}; if ( ! defined($Database) ) { $Database = "database" }
  $Host     = $ENV{MySQLHost};     if ( ! defined($Host)     ) { $Host     = "host" }
  $Port     = $ENV{MySQLPort};     if ( ! defined($Port)     ) { $Port     = 123 }

  $DSN = "DBI:mysql";
  $DSN = $DSN . ":$Database";
  $DSN = $DSN . ";host=$Host";
  $DSN = $DSN . ";port=$Port";
  $DSN = $DSN . ";mysql_compression=1";

  $User     = 'user';
  $Password = 'pw';

  %Options = ( RaiseError => 1 );

  $DBHandle = DBI->connect($DSN, $User, $Password, \%Options);

  return $DBHandle;

}

#=====================================================================================
# Close MySQL connection opened above or a handle that is passed
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLCloseConnection {
  if ( $DBHandle ) { $DBHandle->disconnect }
  return 0;
}

sub MySQLCloseHandle ($) { 
  my ($sh) = @_;
  if ( $sh ) { $sh->finish() }
  return 0;
}

#=====================================================================================
# Return a various database handle values and conditions
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLErrNo      () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_errno'}      }
sub MySQLError      () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_error'}      }
sub MySQLHostInfo   () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_hostinfo'}   }
sub MySQLInfo       () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_info'}       }
sub MySQLInsertID   () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_insertid'}   }
sub MySQLProtoInfo  () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_protoinfo'}  }
sub MySQLServerInfo () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_serverinfo'} }
sub MySQLStat       () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_stat'}       }
sub MySQLThreadID   () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_thread_id'}  }
sub MySQLDBDStats   () { return $DBHandle->{'mysql_dbd_stats'}  }

#=====================================================================================
# Optionally set but always return various database handle values and conditions
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLAutoReconnect (;$) { 
  my $val = $_[0];
  if ( defined($val) ) { $DBHandle->{'mysql_auto_reconnect'} = $val }
  return $DBHandle->{'mysql_auto_reconnect'};
}

sub MySQLUseResult (;$) { 
  my $val = $_[0];
  if ( defined($val) ) { $DBHandle->{'mysql_use_result'} = $val }
  return $DBHandle->{'mysql_use_result'};
}

#=====================================================================================
# Execute MySQL commands and handle errors
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLDoCmd ($;$) {

  my ($MySQLCmd, $Quite) = @_;

  if ( eval { $DBHandle->do($MySQLCmd) } ) {
       open (MYFILE2, '>>/bb/bin/fa/logs/last_sql.txt');
       #!!!!! trying to write warning to log 
       print MYFILE2 MySQLMakeID() . ": $DBHandle->errstr\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";
      return 0;

  } elsif ( ! $Quite ) {
      open (MYFILE, '>>/bb/bin/fa/logs/badsql.txt');
      print MYFILE  MySQLMakeID() . ": $@\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";

#=========SENDS EMAIL ON STATEMENT FAILURE===================    
 while (my ($addressee, $address) = each (%emailList))
     {
         print STDERR "INFO: Sending email to $addressee at address $address\n";
         $message =~ s/ADDRESSEE/$addressee/g;
         $message =~ s/ERRORREASON/$errMessage/g;
         &sendMail($addressee, $address, $message);
         $message =~ s/$addressee/ADDRESSEE/g;
         $message =~ s/$errMessage/ERRORREASON/g;
      }

    return 1;

  } else {
    return 1;

  }

}

#=====================================================================================
# Delete rows from a MySQL table
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLDeleteRows ($;$) {

  my ($Table, $WhereRef) = @_;

  my $WhereList;

  my $MySQLCmd = 'DELETE FROM ' . $Table;

  if ( $WhereRef ) {
    $WhereList = BuildLists ('where', $WhereRef);
    $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . $WhereList;
  }

  return MySQLDoCmd($MySQLCmd);

}


#=====================================================================================
# Select rows from a MySQL table and return a statement handle
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLSelectRows ($$;$$) {

  my ($What, $Table, $WhereRef, $OrderRef) = @_;

  my $MySQLCmd = "SELECT $What FROM $Table";

  if ( $WhereRef ) { $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . BuildLists ('Where'  , $WhereRef) }
  if ( $OrderRef ) { $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . BuildLists ('OrderBy', $OrderRef) }

  # print "MySQLSelectRows: MySQLCmd '$MySQLCmd'\n";

  my $StmtHandle;

  if ( ! eval {  $StmtHandle = $DBHandle->prepare($MySQLCmd) } ) {
    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": $@\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";
    return undef;

  } elsif ( ! eval { $StmtHandle->execute() } ) {
    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": $StmtHandle->errstr\n-->$MySQLCmd<--\n";
    return undef;

  } else {
    return $StmtHandle;

  }

}

#=====================================================================================
# Return a various statement handle values and conditions
#====================================================================================

sub MySQLNumOfFields ($) { my ($sh) = @_; return $sh->{'NUM_OF_FIELDS'}      }
sub MySQLErrStr      ($) { my ($sh) = @_; return $sh->errstr                 }

sub MySQLGetHashRef  ($) { my ($sh) = @_;
  if ( my $Ref = $sh->fetchrow_hashref() ) { return $Ref }
  else                                     { MySQLCloseHandle($sh); return undef } 
}

sub MySQLGetArray ($) { my ($sh) = @_; 
  if ( my $Ref = $sh->fetchrow_array()   ) { return $Ref }
  else                                     { MySQLCloseHandle($sh); return undef } 
}

#=====================================================================================
# Optionally set but always return various statement handle values and conditions
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLUseResults ($;$) { 
  my ($sh, $val) = @_;
  if ( defined($val) ) { $sh->{'mysql_use_result'} = $val }
  return $sh->{'mysql_use_result'};
}

#=====================================================================================
# Update a row in a MySQL table
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLUpdateRows ($$;$) {

  my ($Table, $SetRef, $WhereRef) = @_;

  my $MySQLCmd;
  my $SetList;
  my $WhereList;

  $MySQLCmd = 'UPDATE ' . $Table;

  $SetList = BuildLists ('set', $SetRef);

  $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . $SetList;

  if ( $WhereRef ) {
    $WhereList = BuildLists ('where', $WhereRef);
    $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . $WhereList ;
  }

  # print "MySQLUpdateRows: MySQLCmd '$MySQLCmd'\n";

  return MySQLDoCmd($MySQLCmd);

}



#=====================================================================================
# Truncate a MySQL table
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLTruncateTable ($) {

  my ($Table) = @_;

  my $MySQLCmd = 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' . $Table;

  return MySQLDoCmd($MySQLCmd);

}




#=====================================================================================
#
# The routines below maintain a cache of MySQL values to allow inserting multiple
# rows at a time to improve efficiency
#
#=====================================================================================

#=====================================================================================
# Add a table to the MySQL Cache
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLCacheAddTable ($$;$) {

  my ( $TableName, $FieldNameArray, $DupKeyCmds ) = @_;

  my $DupKeyCmd;

  my $FieldName;
  my $FieldNameString = '';

  for $FieldName ( @$FieldNameArray ) {
    if ( $FieldNameString ) { $FieldNameString = $FieldNameString . ',' }
    $FieldNameString = $FieldNameString . $FieldName;    
  }

    $CacheFieldNameStrings{$TableName} = $FieldNameString;
  @{$CacheFieldNameArrays{$TableName}} = @$FieldNameArray;
  $CacheDupKeyCmds{$TableName}         = $DupKeyCmds;
  $CacheSizes{$TableName}              = 0;
  $CacheFieldValues{$TableName}        = '';

  return 0;

}

#=====================================================================================
# Add a buffer to the MySQL cache
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLCacheAddBuffer ($$) {

  my ( $TableName, $AddValues ) = @_;

  my $FieldName;
  my $FieldValue;
  my $FieldValues;

  my $CacheValues;

  if ( ! defined($CacheFieldNameStrings{$TableName}) ) {
    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": Table '$TableName' has not been initialized with the 'AddTable' command\n"; 
    return 1;
  }

  if ( $CacheSizes{$TableName} >= $MaxCacheSize ) { 
    # if ( $TableName eq 'tbl_xyz' ) {
      # print "Flushing $TableName cache before adding buffer: CacheSize = '$CacheSizes{$TableName}'\n" }
    MySQLCacheFlush ($TableName);
  }

  $FieldValues = '';

  for $FieldName ( @{$CacheFieldNameArrays{$TableName}} ) {

    $FieldValue = $AddValues->{$FieldName};

    if ( ! defined($FieldValue) ) { $FieldValue  =  '' }                 # Make sure value is defined
    else                          { $FieldValue  =~ s/(["',\\])/\\$1/g } # Make sure that MySQL special chars are escaped

    if ( $FieldValues ) { $FieldValues =  $FieldValues . "," }

    $FieldValues =  $FieldValues . "'" . $FieldValue . "'";

  }

  $CacheValues = $CacheFieldValues{$TableName};

  if ( $CacheValues ) { $CacheValues = $CacheValues . ',' }

  $CacheValues = $CacheValues . '(' . $FieldValues . ')';

  $CacheFieldValues{$TableName} = $CacheValues;

  $CacheSizes{$TableName}++;

  # if ( $TableName eq 'tbl_xyz' ) {
    # print "Added buffer to $TableName cache: CacheSizes '$CacheSizes{$TableName}', CacheValues '$CacheValues'\n" }

  return 0;

}

#=====================================================================================
# Flush entries from MySQL cache
#=====================================================================================

sub MySQLCacheFlush ($) {

  my ( $TableName ) = @_;

  my $FlushTable;
  my @FlushTables,

  my $FieldNames;
  my $FieldValues;
  my $DupKeyCmd;

  my $MySQLCmd;

  if ( lc($TableName) eq 'all' ) { 
    for $FlushTable ( keys(%CacheFieldNameStrings) ) { push @FlushTables, $FlushTable }

  } elsif ( ! defined($CacheFieldNameStrings{$TableName}) ) {
    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": Table '$TableName' has not been initialized with the 'AddTable' command\n"; 
    return 1;

  } else {
    push @FlushTables, $TableName;

  }

  FlushTable: for $FlushTable ( @FlushTables ) {

    $FieldValues = $CacheFieldValues{$FlushTable};

    $CacheFieldValues{$FlushTable} = '';
    $CacheSizes{$FlushTable}       = 0;

    if ( ! $FieldValues ) { next FlushTable }

    $FieldNames = $CacheFieldNameStrings{$FlushTable};
    $DupKeyCmd  = $CacheDupKeyCmds{$FlushTable};

#Removed DELAYED after moving to innodb
#$MySQLCmd = "INSERT DELAYED INTO $FlushTable ($FieldNames) VALUES $FieldValues";

 $MySQLCmd = "INSERT INTO $FlushTable ($FieldNames) VALUES $FieldValues";

    if ( $DupKeyCmd ) { $MySQLCmd = $MySQLCmd . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' . $DupKeyCmd }

    return MySQLDoCmd($MySQLCmd);

  }

}

sub BuildLists ($$;$) {

  my ($Type, $Ref1, $Ref2) = @_;

  my $Ref1Type = ref($Ref1);
  my $Ref2Type = ref($Ref2);

  my $Name;
  my $NameList;
  my $Value;
  my $ValueList;

  my %Fields;

  my $RtnVal;

  $Type = lc($Type);

  my $TypeIndex = index('values set where orderby', $Type);

  # print "Type '$Type', TypeIndex '$TypeIndex', Ref1Type '$Ref1Type', Ref1 '$Ref1'\n";

  if ( $TypeIndex < 0 ) {

    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": $Type is not a a valid type. Use 'values', 'set' or 'where'\n";
    return $RtnVal;

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq '' ) {

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {
      $RtnVal = '(' . $Ref1 . ') VALUES (' . $Ref2 . ')';
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'orderby' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' ORDER BY ' . $Ref1;
    }

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq 'SCALAR' ) {

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {
      $RtnVal = '(' . $$Ref1 . ') VALUES (' . $$Ref2 . ')';
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $$Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $$Ref1;    
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'orderby' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' ORDER BY ' . $$Ref1;
    }

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq 'HASH' ) {

    for $Name ( keys(%$Ref1) )  {

      $Value = $Ref1->{$Name};

      if ( ! defined($Value) ) { $Value  =  '' }                 # Make sure value is defined
      else                     { $Value  =~ s/(["',\\])/\\$1/g } # Make sure that MySQL special chars are escaped

      $Fields{$Name} = $Value;

    }

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {

      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $NameList ) {
          $NameList  = $NameList  . ','  . $Name;
          $ValueList = $ValueList . ',"' . $Value . '"';
        } else {
          $NameList  = $Name;
          $ValueList = '"' . $Value . '"';    
        }
      }

      $RtnVal = " ($NameList) VALUES ($ValueList)";

    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = '';
      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $RtnVal ) { $RtnVal = $RtnVal . ',' }
        $RtnVal = $RtnVal . $Name . '="' . $Value . '"';
      }
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $RtnVal;

    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = '';
      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $RtnVal ) { $RtnVal = $RtnVal . ' AND ' }
        $RtnVal = $RtnVal . '(' . $Name . '="' . $Value . '")';
      }
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $RtnVal;

    }

  } else {

    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": Parameter two is unsupported reference type '$Ref1Type'\n";
    return $RtnVal;

  }

  return $RtnVal;

}

sub BuildListsInt ($$;$) {

  my ($Type, $Ref1, $Ref2) = @_;
  my $Ref1Type = ref($Ref1);
  my $Ref2Type = ref($Ref2);

  my $Name;
  my $NameList;
  my $Value;
  my $ValueList;

  my %Fields;

  my $RtnVal;

  $Type = lc($Type);

  my $TypeIndex = index('values set where orderby', $Type);

  # print "Type '$Type', TypeIndex '$TypeIndex', Ref1Type '$Ref1Type', Ref1 '$Ref1'\n";

  if ( $TypeIndex < 0 ) {

    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": $Type is not a a valid type. Use 'values', 'set' or 'where'\n";
    return $RtnVal;

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq '' ) {

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {
      $RtnVal = '(' . $Ref1 . ') VALUES (' . $Ref2 . ')';
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'orderby' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' ORDER BY ' . $Ref1;
    }

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq 'SCALAR' ) {

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {
      $RtnVal = '(' . $$Ref1 . ') VALUES (' . $$Ref2 . ')';
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $$Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $$Ref1;
    } elsif ( $Type eq 'orderby' ) {
      $RtnVal = ' ORDER BY ' . $$Ref1;
    }

  } elsif ( $Ref1Type eq 'HASH' ) {

    for $Name ( keys(%$Ref1) )  {

      $Value = $Ref1->{$Name};

      if ( ! defined($Value) ) { $Value  =  '' }                 # Make sure value is defined
      else                     { $Value  =~ s/(["',\\])/\\$1/g } # Make sure that MySQL special chars are escaped

      $Fields{$Name} = $Value;

    }

    if ( $Type eq 'values' ) {

      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $NameList ) {
          $NameList  = $NameList  . ','  . $Name;
          $ValueList = $ValueList . ',"' . $Value . '"';
        } else {
          $NameList  = $Name;
          $ValueList = '"' . $Value . '"';
        }
      }

      $RtnVal = " ($NameList) VALUES ($ValueList)";

    } elsif ( $Type eq 'set' ) {
      $RtnVal = '';
      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $RtnVal ) { $RtnVal = $RtnVal . ',' }
        $RtnVal = $RtnVal . $Name . '="' . $Value . '"';
      }
      $RtnVal = ' SET ' . $RtnVal;

    } elsif ( $Type eq 'where' ) {
      $RtnVal = '';
      while (($Name, $Value) = each %Fields ) {
        if ( $RtnVal ) { $RtnVal = $RtnVal . ' AND ' }
        $RtnVal = $RtnVal . '(' . $Name . '=' . $Value . ')';
      }
      $RtnVal = ' WHERE ' . $RtnVal;

    }

  } else {

    print STDERR MySQLMakeID() . ": Parameter two is unsupported reference type '$Ref1Type'\n";
    return $RtnVal;

  }

  return $RtnVal;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask two questions.

### How do I capture MySQL warnings?

> *1)If the statement executes but there is a mysql warning I want to capture that to last_sql_warning.txt*

The **easiest way** to do this is simply to promote MySQL warnings to errors, which you already know you can log.   This will do the trick:  `$DBHandle->do(q|SET sql_mode='traditional'|);`

A **harder way** is to enumerate the warnings via `SHOW WARNINGS`, which you can check if the `mysql_warning_count` attribute reports that warnings were encountered.  At the time of this writing, however, `DBD::mysql` inconveniently exposes that attribute only for statement (not database) handles.

***UPDATED:** `DBD::mysql` since 4.025 (2013-11-05) supports this attribute on database handles, so the code below could be simplified to a `$dbh->{mysql_warning_count}` check.*

Thus, you might do something like this:

```
my $warnings;
my $ok = eval {
           my $sth = $DBHandle->prepare($MySQLCmd);
           $sth->execute();
           $warnings = $sth->{mysql_warning_count};
           1;
         };

unless ($ok) {                   # Some error encountered
  ... # log it
} elsif ($warnings) {            # Some warning(s) encountered
  ... # open log file

  my $warnings = $DBHandle->selectall_arrayref('SHOW WARNINGS');
  for my $row (@$warnings) {
    # @$row is something like ('Warning', 1265, "Data truncated for column 'col' at row 1")
    ... # log it
  }
}
```

### How do I retry a statement that failed due to a particular error?

> *2)If the statement failes do to a lock timeout i would like to re-submit the query up to two times*

In your error handling branch, inspect `$DBHandle->err` for the MySQL error code you care about (probably no. 1205, [ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_lock_wait_timeout)), and retry as appropriate.

Comment: I will try this out in a few hours but this looks like it is on the right track.   Thanks..

Comment: The capture warning works like a champ.   I have no tried to 'retry' the transacdtion but now that I have the the proper info being returned I am sure I can figure the rest out.

Comment: Caution: sql_mode='traditional' turns some, but not all, warnings into errors.  "A simple description of this mode is “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column." - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#id544805.  An example of a warning not promoted to an error by sql_mode='traditional' is "1 line(s) were cut by GROUP_CONCAT()".